# Task 'assembleDebug' not found in root project 'android' for Flutter projec in VS Code

Tags: android, flutter

I am brand new to flutter and just trying to get a hello world app to run.
I have installed all the things i need to, when I run flutter doctor i get told everything is installed, green ticks all the way down the list.

Then I open the app in VS Code, open an Android simulator from Android Studio, and run flutter run.

But then I get the following:

[image]

Anyone know what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

i had the same issue.
the problem for me was that i didn't had settings.gradle under root project so, add that file under root project and add this line in it

```
include ':app'
```

hope it works.